# How the WordPress custom loop works

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

This might seem like a bit of a strange question but there's something that I'm finding really hard to understand so was hoping someone could clear it up for me.

If I create a new instance of the WP_Query object for a custom loop to work along side the main default loop, lets say this custom loop is the first thing on the page, I then need to reset the custom loop before using the default one?

Is that correct? The thing I'm finding hard to understand is that if I've created a separate instance of the WP_Query object then how is this affecting the main default page loop? Is it because the $post global variable gets altered by my custom loop?

Thanks very much for any help, I've been searching for ages on the Internet for an answer and none of the ones I've found (of which there are quite a few) are really clearing this up for me.

Comment: The purpose of creating a new instance of the WP_Query, and a new loop, is so that it *does not effect* the main loop.  So if you use a custom loop, there is no worries about effecting your main loop - it will still work perfectly.

Comment: Wordpress is built upon global variables, see how this can be bad

Comment: @cale_b you see that's exactly what I thought but in the past I've had to reset the query and I've been trying to understand why as they are separate instances and shouldn't be interacting as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @DamienPirsy So what you're saying is that when I create a custom WP_Query object and loop through it the results override the same global variable that the default loop of the pages uses? Is that correct.

I have to say to me that seems a little silly, why on Earth is it designed that way?